# How can I stop css files from being precompiled in rails test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline

I'm looking for a way to modify my test environment so that the JS files get precompiled but the CSS (SASS) files do not get precompiled.

The reason I want to do this is that I have some capybara feature specs which are running with the `js: true` flag using phantomjs. These tests take a lot of time before running as I have to set `config.assets.compile` to `true` in `config/environments/test.rb` for the JS feature tests to work and the CSS compilation takes a long time because of my bloated CSS files.

I've tried setting `config.assets.compile` to `[/(?:\/|\\|\A)application\.js$/]` only, but I still see SASS compilation happening.

Comment: I think you can just do config.assets.precompile -= <regex to exclude only .scss files>

Comment: @ruby_newbie I tried that, but the I saw dynamic compilation happening in tests when rspec reached the test with `js: true` flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the settings that worked for me finally after some trial and error. Also, it's best to run `RAILS_ENV=test rake assets:precompile` before the tests.

```
# in config/environments/test.rb
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.precompile = [/(?:\/|\\|\A)application\.js$/]


# in app/view/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" unless Rails.env.test? %>
```